# Saving ggplot plot in R with deeper color depth than PNG-8 format

Tags: r, ggplot2, png

In R, the default settings to save a PNG file (e.g. ggplot/ggsave) is always the PNG-8 format, which allows up to 256 (2^8) colors. How can I save a image with deep color depth, such as 16/24-bit color? So I can get a "True color' image.

```
  ggplot(mtcars)+ geom_point(aes(x=gear,y=mpg))  
  ggsave('car.png')
```

Comment: From ?png: *png will normally use a palette* [ie this means PNG8] *if there are less than 256 colours on the page, and record a 24-bit RGB file otherwise (or a 32-bit ARGB file if type = "cairo" and non-opaque colours are used). However, type = "cairo-png" uses cairographics' PNG backend which will never use a palette and normally creates a larger 32-bit ARGB file—this may work better for specialist uses with semi-transparent colours.* You may need to employ more graduated colors in your chart to get a different PNG output.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cairographics for that. This should default to a larger format.

```
install.packages("Cairo")
library(Cairo)

ggsave("car.png", type = "cairo-png")
```

Comment: I used the Photoshop software to check the format of the new picture. It is now in RGB color rather than Index color. Great progress!  However, it still says 8 Bits/channel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyway to specify bit depth with ggsave. However, you could use different file types to work around it. ggsave using .tiff files appears to default to 24 bit depth. If your file has to be .png you may be able to convert it after saving as a tiff.

`ggsave('car.tiff')`